# Поменять i бит числа на 1 или 0

Tags: golang

Всем привет

Стоит задача Поменять i-й бит числа в 1 или 0. Я сделал так, но меня смущает что много приведений типов и кода в принципе много для такой задачи. Как еще это можно сделать?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

func IntToBits(num int) string {
    return strconv.FormatInt(int64(num), 2)
}

func bitsToInt(s string) int64 {
    newVal, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 2, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return newVal
}

func changeOneBit(num, position, newBit int) int64 {
    if position > 0 && num == 0 {
        return int64(num)
    }

    if newBit > 1 || newBit < 0 {
        log.Println("Новый бит может быть только 1 или 0")
        return int64(num)
    }

    bits := []byte(IntToBits(num))
    fmt.Printf("Было \t %s(%v)\n", string(bits), num)

    if position >= len(bits) {
        log.Printf("В числе %v нет %v разрядов. Разярядов в числе %v только %v\n", num, position, num, len(bits))
        return int64(num)
    }

    newB := []byte(IntToBits(newBit))
    bits[position] = newB[0]
    newVal := bitsToInt(string(bits))
    fmt.Printf("Стало \t %s(%v)\n", string(bits), newVal)
    return newVal
}
func main(){
    log.Println(changeOneBit(12, 3, 1)) //8
}
```

Comment: посмотрите в сторону битовых операций

Comment: @MaksimFedorov я смотрел туда, но не нашел нужные мне операции. Не вижу где там можно поменять i-ый бит в 1 или 0

Comment: Как насчет [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192262/how-would-you-set-and-clear-a-single-bit-in-go) решения?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как оно может изменить один конкретный бит. Ведь операции которые там производятся, они производятся над всеми битами а не над одним конкретным. Если я понял бинарные операторы (и не, и, или, исключающее или, сдвиги), они производятся над всеми битами. Я не могу с их помощью изменить один единственный бит в числе. В курсе по си вообще говорят  что в ассемблере есть такой функционал(менять только один бит), получается что даже в си такого нет,  разве в го такое может быть?

Comment: @Quester используемое там число `1 << pos` содержит только один установленный бит, поэтому и все операции производятся только над одним конкретным битом — тем, который установлен в этом самом числе `1 << pos`

Comment: @Quester, читайте про [бинарный сдвиг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3) и [битовые маски](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы поменять только один k-й бит, нужно создать маску - число с таким набором битов, что при выполнении соответствующей побитовой операции изменится только нужный бит, а остальные останутся неизменными.

Для операции установки бита c помощью побитового OR это маска вида `0b00001000`, а для операции сброса бита c помощью побитового AND маска вида `0b11110111`

Первую легко получить, сдвинув единицу на k позиций.

А вторую - побитово инвертировав первую.

Пример: нужно установить третий бит

```
01010110
     ^ вот этот
mask=00000001 << 3  = 00001000

01010110   or
00001000
--------
01011110
```

Операция or c нулевыми битами маски не меняет соответствующие биты числа.

Теперь в результате сбросим это же бит

```
mask = not(00000001 << 3) = not(00001000) = 11110111

01011110  and
11110111
--------
01010110
```

Операция and c единичными битами маски не меняет соответствующие биты числа.

В обоих случаях все биты, кроме третьего, остались прежними

Comment: Что-то не въезжаю. Если я сдвигаю на еденицу вправо, то меняются все биты, кроме тех которые повторяются 2 и более раз то есть если есть биты 101010110 то после сдвига на еденицу будет 010101010, один 0 в конца отсекся, а 11 превратилос в 10 и перенеслось в конец

Comment: А если число 101010110 сдвинуть на один влево как в примере по ссылке в комментах к вопросу, то после сдвига будет 010101100. И что там, что там меняется полностью вся последовательность. Что то не пойму, какая такая маска получается при сдвиге

Comment: Число, в котором нужно менять бит - никуда не сдвигается. На него накладывается маска, в вот эта маска получается из числа 1 с помощью сдвига

Comment: @Quester Ну что, разобрались?

Comment: Да, я понял вроде все. маска это отдельная последовательность бит. Если я правильно все понял, то все что в маске нули, то не меняется в целевой последовательности бит, а то что 1 то меняется. А сдвиг нужн чтобы еденицу передвинуть на целевую позицию для изменения. Это конечно вольный пересказ))) Не понял только почему если делается сдвиг единицы на нужное количество бит, то этот сдвиг происходит с конца последовательности

Comment: `все что в маске нули, то не меняется в целевой последовательности бит` именно при операции or.  то `что 1 то меняется` - точнее, устанавливается в 1. Если было 1, то и останется. `если делается сдвиг единицы на нужное количество бит, то этот сдвиг происходит с конца последовательности ` чтобы единица переместилась с нулевого места на нужное

Comment: а почему нулевой -  первый справа а не слева?

Comment: нулевой - младший бит числа, принято записывать справа (так же как десятичные числа - младший разряд справа)

Comment: а в целом индексация битов идет стандартно 0,1,2,3,4...? не с 1 начинается?

Comment: Чаще с нуля, да, но может и нумерация с единицы использоваться.

Comment: А от чего это зависит? От реализации, платформы, или чего то другого?

Comment: от людей, которые как хотят, так и нумеруют ;)

Comment: Только вот не могу понять, как мне получить маску. Допустим у меня число 555(1000101011), я хочу в нем поменять  4 бит, мне нужно получить такое 0000000001, чтобы сдвинуть 1 на нужную позицию. Как мне получить это число из нулей по количеству битов числа с последней еденицей?

Comment: Так единица и есть 0000000001, сдвигаем её на 4 разряда, получим 000010000

Comment: получить такую запись можно сделав 1<<4?

Comment: получить такое значение маски - да именно так. Что имеется в виду под записью?

Comment: когда у меня есть число 555(1000101011) и пытаюсь получить маску сделав 1<<4 то получаю 10000 а не 00000010000

Comment: это одно и то же.

Comment: спасибо, все таки разобрался)))Но возникли дополнительные трудности. Биты меняются но есть [загвоздка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414349/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) при задании позиции

Comment: Ну вам там всё правильно говорят. Числа занимают 8, 16, 32 или 64 бит. Все биты числа конкретного размера существуют в любом случае, а каким образом вы их видите -  с ведущими нулями или без - зависит от способа вывода